# Restart Spyder IPython console in script

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder, restart

Currently I am doing some debugging on a script but when I run it the second time I get a false outcome. Now I want to restart the IPython console everytime when I run my script e.i. I want to include it in my script and do it automatically. I already tried to clear and restart my console but that doesn’t work. Has somebody an idea how I can solve this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to clear out all variables from previous run when you re-run the script? If yes, you can change the preference settings in Spyder.

Go to Tools > Preferences > Run > Check the box that says "Clear all variables before execution."

[image]

Comment: If this solves your problem, kindly consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer